# Adding "tokens" to a array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out for an assignment how to take tokens from a txt file (which are sets of letters/numbers that don't have a space separating them) and add them to a array.

My array is set up like this

```
private String[] arrayOfTokens;
```

The txt file reads like this

```
10 tewnty 30.5 star-fish -5
1 two 3
4 five 6 seven
jello 9 hike 5
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Just to be clear the first line would have 5 tokens ("10", "twenty", "30.5", "star-fish", and "-5") and the second would have 3 ("1", "two", and "3")

One of the things throwing me off however is that it says this... "The first text line would result in the five tokens being stored in locations [0][0], [0][1] , [0][2] , [0][3], and [0][4]. The second text line would result in the three tokens being stored in locations [1][0], [1][1], and [1][2].". It only says that I need one array so I am not sure what that is about.

I have simply searched online for some things but what I have found just puts the whole txt file in to an array. I am just trying to add the tokens. Anyone have anything that could get me on the right track?

Comment: You need a two-dimensional array or, to be more precise, an array of arrays. If the assignment text explicitly says that "exactly one array is needed", then the formulation of the assignment is wrong and the exercise, as given, is not solveable, expecially since you need ragged arrays. You can find the basics in [this oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: oh geez. Let me go do some research on what that is lol..

Comment: hmmm it says "Store the token found on each text line in a 2D array. This 2D array must store String objects." which leads me to believe it is just one array

Comment: No, it is not really. Your professor/teacher may call it "one array" for the sake of simplicity, but a two-dimensional array in java is really an array of arrays. [This site](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/jagged-arrays-in-java/) explains the concept of multidimensional arrays quite well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a jagged array to solve the problem. A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays but the can be of different dimensions and sizes. Here is a code that you can try :

```
int numberOfLineOfTheFile;  /* put the number of line of your file here */
String[][] tokens = new String[numberOfLineOfTheFile][];
String[] arrayOfTokens;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       arrayOfTokens = line.split(" ");
       tokens[i++] = arrayOfTokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation to your answer. Also, OP did not ask for a ready-to-copy answer but for some explanation/hints to get her/him going in the right direction. EDIT: no, I did not downvote your answer.